# Aggregate Issue with Redis Search

Tags: redis, redisearch

I have recently started learning Redis Search and encountered a few issues while working on a specific example. I am storing multiple entries, each containing a tag called `accountID` and a `size`. My goal is to calculate the sum of sizes for each account.

Here's my hash template:

```
HSET my-key:<<unique_ID>> accountID <<acc>> size <<the size>>
```

Example:

```
HSET my-key:1 accountID acc1 size 100
HSET my-key:2 accountID acc1 size 100
HSET my-key:3 accountID acc2 size 100
```

To calculate the total size per `accountID`, I created the following index:

```
FT.CREATE storageUsageIdx ON hash PREFIX 1 "my-key:" SCHEMA accountID TAG SORTABLE size NUMERIC
```

And here's my aggregation query:

```
FT.AGGREGATE storageUsageIdx "*" GROUPBY 1 @accountID REDUCE SUM 1 @size AS total_usage
```

This query works well when the number of entries is below 500k.

```
FT.AGGREGATE storageUsage "*" GROUPBY 1 @accountID REDUCE SUM 1 @size AS total_usage
1) "1"
2) 1) "accountID"
   2) "acc1"
   3) "total_usage"
   4) "880800"
```

However, when the number of entries exceeds a certain threshold, the result is always null:

```
FT.AGGREGATE storageUsageIdx "*" GROUPBY 1 @accountID REDUCE SUM 1 @size AS total_usage
1) "1"
2) 1) "accountID"
   2) "null"
   3) "total_usage"
   4) "0"
```

Interestingly, when I filter by `accountID`, I get the expected result:

```
FT.AGGREGATE storageUsageIdx "*" FILTER "@accountID == 'acc1'" GROUPBY 1 @accountID REDUCE SUM 1 @size AS total_usage
1) "1"
2) 1) "accountID"
   2) "acc1"
   3) "total_usage"
   4) "100000000"
```

There are 1M entries for `accountID =acc1` with a size of 100, so the result is correct. This query takes around 3 seconds to execute.

I also added 100 more entries for `accountID =acc2`, and the query to calculate the total size also takes the same amount of time. This leads me to believe that my index configuration might be incorrect?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving this aggregate issue and optimizing my index configuration.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hi there - I was initially thinking you might be hitting the query timeout, but 3 seconds would be longer than the default 500ms for that (see https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/configuring/) .  Similarly I wondered if you had hit the MAXSEARCHRESULTS value (default 1000000) but I guess not.  

Then l thought maybe its MAXAGGREGATERESULTS that you are hitting but default for that seems to be unlimited too. Can you run FT.CONFIG GET * and post your output?  Thsi may help with diagnosis.

Comment: Additionally would suggest removing RedisGear from the title here and going with RediSearch.  Redis Gears is a different product that's not involved in this question.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading title. I'm fixing it.
Regarding FT.CONFIG, I just noticed it is not available. I'm using Redis Enterprise and they disabled a few redis commands.

Comment: Can you try to use SlowLog https://redis.io/commands/slowlog-get/ and see what you get?

Comment: @SimonPrickett I think you were right. Redis Enterprise is blacklisting a ton of useful redis comands. One is the `FT.CONFIG GET`. I just did a test on a community based image and I had no issues getting the result that I wanted once I increased the timeout: `FT.CONFIG SET TIMEOUT 3000`

Answer (score 2):

In your last query, you have a problem; when you use `FILTER`, your filter will be applied after `aggregation`, so your query is faced with all of your data and filter that after `aggregation`.
According to documentation,[ft.aggregate](https://redis.io/commands/ft.aggregate/)

> FILTER {expr}: filters the results using predicate expressions relating to values in each result. They are applied post-query and relate to the current state of the pipeline.

So, you can change your last query as follows:

```
FT.AGGREGATE storageUsageIdx "@accountID:{acc1}" GROUPBY 1 @accountID REDUCE SUM 1 @size AS total_usage
```

This query will be significantly faster.